# Cannot find in scope SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, error-handling, compiler-errors

I am currently completing a task on Codecademy, and am running into an issue. I created a new view called "ChoiceTextView", and it is supposed to shorten up my code so the code can reference this view. The issue I am running into is when I try to reference it, I receive the error "Cannot find 'ChoiceTextView' in scope'.

Here is the code from ChoiceTextView

```
    import SwiftUI

struct ChoiceTextView: View {
    let choiceText: String
    
    let accentColor = Color(red: 48/255, green: 105/255, blue: 240/255)
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(choiceText)
            .font(.body)
            .bold()
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .padding()
            .border(accentColor, width: 4)
    }
}

struct ChoiceTextView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ChoiceTextView(choiceText: "Choice Text!")
    }
}
```

Here is the code that is throwing the error:

```
    Button(action: { print("Tapped on Choice 1")},
label:{ChoiceTextView(choiceText: question.possibleAnswers[0])
                    })
```

I hope I summarized my issue correctly. Please let me know if you have any questions, and thank you.

Comment: Look at your `Button` code carefully. You are missing a closing parenthesis on your print statement

Comment: @jnpdx That was my bad when formatting this post. The code includes the closing parenthesis, and is still throwing the error

Comment: Is the file including `ChoiceTextView` added to your target?

Comment: @jnpdx What does target mean? How do I add a file to my target? I tried googling, but I don't think I found the correct information

Comment: Click on the top-most item in the left-hand sidebar in Xcode (the project navigator). Go to Build Phases and see if the file with `ChoiceTextView` is added under "Compile Sources". There's also a section in the right sidebar called "Target Membership" that will show you what target each file is added to.

Comment: @jnpdx I think I found the issue. The type was set to plain text. I made the type swift source and the error messages went away! For future context though, I don't have a "compile sources" in my project navigator. Just code history and preview content. I do have the target membership though, which is showing only my main program

Comment: You do have a "compile sources" -- it's just not quite where you're looking. Make sure you've clicked on the topmost item in the Project Navigator and then explore the main panel.